# run certain program without sudo but with password prompt

Tags: sudo

I want to be able to run `visudo` without `sudo` (because `visudo` obviously wants to be used as root), but I *want* it to prompt for my password (for security reason). Is there any way to do this? Something opposite of `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: `alias visudo='sudo visudo'`

Answer (score 1):

You can't have it both ways.

Only `root` has the ability to edit the `sudoers` file which is what `visudo` does. The default permissions for the `sudoers` file are `440` which is why `visudo` is used to edit it and only root can use that command.

The `sudo` command will refuse to work if the permissions for the `sudoers` file are not `440` in order to avoid ruining the system.

It's not worth the trouble just so you can attempt to avoid typing `sudo` because it will just break your system and not work anyway. The security that you are looking for is already in place.

Comment: `visudo` does more than that, it locks the sudoers file while you're editing it and it also syntax checks the edits before allowing you to commit them.

Comment: @slm Yes, it does, which is why it should always be used instead of using a text editor on the `sudoers` file itself. In this case, I was only trying to explain why it's not a good idea to mess with that file just for the purpose of not having to use `sudo` when using the `visudo` command.

Comment: Just expanding, not being critical 8-)

Comment: I have seen `docker` and `systemctl` doing it this way, so I thought that there is a general solution.

Comment: @slm It's cool and the information you added is very useful.

Comment: @FranklinYu If you are in the `docker` group then you don't need to use `sudo` to use the `docker` command. You can actually use it to gain `root` to the whole system but that's a different story.  By default, you can use `systemctl` without being `root` or using `sudo` unless you want to start or stop services.

Comment: @NasirRiley Then how did docker make it? Do they rely on the Unix socket permission for that?

Comment: @FranklinYu The user has to be in the docker group. Otherwise, you need `root/sudo`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Then what's special about docker group? What did docker do to the docker group? Can I create a `sudoers-editor` group so that user in this group can access `/etc/sudoers` without sudo?

Comment: @FranklinYu The `docker` group has rights to run the `docker` commands. The `sudoers` file can only be accessed and edited by `root` which includes doing it via the `visudo` command.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, I understand that. I'm just wondering how the docker team *implemented* this feature? Can I implement the same to my own program? I already know *what*; I just want to know *how*.